# python pandas dataframe indexing

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(carData)
df.column['models']
#df.ffill() This is where i need to fill the amount of columns i want to add with previous value
```

The data looks something like

```
          models
1         honda
2         ford
3         chevy
```

I want to add an index but keep it numerical up to a certain number and forward fill the models column to the last value. so for example the dataset above has 3 entries, I want to add an have a total of 5 entries it should look something like

```
          models
1         honda
2         ford
3         chevy
4         chevy
5         chevy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
N= 5
df.reindex(range(N)).ffill()

    models
0   honda
1   ford
2   chevy
3   chevy
4   chevy
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'` or add `ffill`:

```
N = 5
df = df.reindex(np.arange(1, N + 1), method='ffill')
#alternative
#df = df.reindex(np.arange(1, N + 1)).ffill()
print (df)
  models
1  honda
2   ford
3  chevy
4  chevy
5  chevy
```

If default `RangeIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

N = 5
df = df.reindex(np.arange(N), method='ffill')
#alternative
#df = df.reindex(np.arange(N)).ffill()
print (df)
  models
0  honda
1   ford
2  chevy
3  chevy
4  chevy
```